# Native formula to check if range of non-blank cells are equal

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have three cells, any combination of which can be blank.  I want to check if all non-blank cells are equal.  If cells 1 and 2 have a value and cell 3 is blank, I want the formula to return TRUE if cells 1 and 2 are equal.

If there is no *native* formula for this then I will just write a VBA macro.

**Update**:  It was actually quicker to just write a VBA macro.  I am a .NET/c# developer and have forgotten a lot of my VBA from back in the day, so I am open for improvements on my code here (especially setting the return value and exiting the function).

```
Public Function NonblankValuesAreEqual(cells As Range) As Boolean

Dim lastval As String

lastval = cells(1).Value

For i = 2 To cells.Count
    If lastval <> "" Then
        If cells(i).Value <> "" Then
            If cells(i).Value <> lastval Then
                NonblankValuesAreEqual = False
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    End If
    lastval = cells(i).Value
Next

NonblankValuesAreEqual = True

End Function
```

Comment: @Steven TRUE would be fine since the dynamics of the formula would dictate that it is equal to itself.

Comment: @Kyle Googling.  My next step is to write a VBA macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already answered yourself with a macro, but here is a non-VBA solution. It's an array formula, and must be confirmed with ctrl+shift+enter:

```
=(SUM(IFERROR(1/COUNTIF(A1:A3,A1:A3),0))=1)
```

This formula counts the number of unique values in your range, while ignoring blank cells. If the number of unique values is 1, then every value is the same and the formula returns TRUE. The only thing that wasn't specified in your question is what to do if every cell is blank. Right now the formula will return TRUE, but it would be easy to add some additional logic to change that.

Comment: Keep in mind this solution is case-insensitive (ie: a = A).

Comment: Impressive!  It works.  I've tried wrapping my head around array functions, but to no avail.  I can copy/paste/modify them, but I just cannot write them.  Maybe someday.  My particular needs don't require case-sensitivity, but I assume someone else's possibly could.  I'll let this one spin for a bit before I mark it as answer.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin Glad you like it. The quick and dirty is that array formulas take one or more of the same sized ranges or arrays, calculate the formula as many times as their are elements in your array/range, and return an array of the same size as well. That's why, generally, you have to feed the results into something that naturally handles arrays, like SUM().

Comment: What is considered a blank here? I have formulas in my cells that return "" in some cases, and those did not seem to work with this formula (but it worked if I deleted those formulas out of the cells that returned the "").

Answer (score 2):

Check if each column-pair exactly equal (case-sensitive) or contain a blank.

```
=OR(EXACT(A2,B2),ISBLANK(A2),ISBLANK(B2))
=OR(EXACT(A2,C2),ISBLANK(A2),ISBLANK(C2))
=OR(EXACT(B2,C2),ISBLANK(B2),ISBLANK(C2))

=AND(D2:F2)
```

Example:

```
A   B   C   AB      AC      BC      AND
1   1   1   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
1   1       TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
A           TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
    A       TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
        A   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
a   A   a   FALSE   TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
a   a       TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
a       2   TRUE    FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
    A   A   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
A       A   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
    A   B   TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
A   B   C   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
```

Note: For larger sets, the number of adjacent columns will increase greatly: n! / 2

Comment: This works only for numeric types.  Try a, b, a.  This formula should work for strings as well, though it's a creative way to do it for numeric types.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin See updated answer for a non-VBA solution for strings and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`=COUNTA(A:A)=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)`

Basically count the number of nonblank cells.
Count the number of cells matching the first cell.
If those are the same, then they must all be the same.
It doesn't really matter who you count for the 2nd COUNTIF ... since it won't likely be equal to COUNTA if they aren't all the same ;)

[edit]
if your first cell could be blank .. try this instead:

`=COUNTA(A:A)=COUNTIF(A:A,VLOOKUP("*",A:A,1,FALSE))`

it'll try to find the first non-blank cell to check in the COUNTIF ..

Comment: But what if A1 is blank?

Comment: hmm, cute .. typically the blank cells are later on, not the first one .. but yeah, you'll have to find the first non blank cell ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this small *UDF()*:

```
Public Function EqualTest(r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range) As Variant
   Dim BlankCount As Long, v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant, v3 As Variant
   v1 = r1.Value
   v2 = r2.Value
   v3 = r3.Value
   BlankCount = 0
   If v1 = "" Then BlankCount = BlankCount + 1
   If v2 = "" Then BlankCount = BlankCount + 1
   If v3 = "" Then BlankCount = BlankCount + 1

   If BlankCount > 1 Then
      EqualTest = True
      Exit Function
   End If

   If BlankCount = 0 Then
      If v1 = v2 And v1 = v3 And v2 = v3 Then
         EqualTest = True
         Exit Function
      Else
         EqualTest = False
         Exit Function
      End If
   End If

   If v1 = v2 Or v1 = v3 Or v2 = v3 Then
      EqualTest = True
   Else
      EqualTest = False
   End If
End Function
```

[image]

NOTE:

The cells do not have to be contiguous and the *UDF()* will work for both numeric cells and text cells.

Comment: Not a very dynamic solution.  What if my range consists of four cells?  You posted this just as I posted a VBA solution in my answer, so take a look.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin My code meets the original Post specifying ***3*** cells.

Comment: You should always think dynamically rather than taking a literal approach.  Plus, look how much more code yours consists of and it's not even scalable.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin I like your code also.